# If Atheism is the rejection of all deities equally what is the polar opposite?

Tags: meaning

If an 'atheist' is someone that does not believe in all deities with equal disbelief, what would you call someone **that believes in all deities** equally?

Comment: Polar theism, the proposition that all the gods are hiding at the N--wait, what was the question?

Comment: I would suggest that atheism is in the disbelief in the existence of a theistic being. It usually subcategorised into either *Agnostic atheism* (those who don't claim to know of the non-existence of a God) or *Gnostic atheism* (those who claim to know that God does not exist). To say the opposite of this is therefore a somewhat undefined question since it really depends upon which position you're coming from. I would also add that Pantheism is really rather the belief that all exists as part of the Divine. http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pantheism/

Comment: I know a number of people who consider themselves agnostic, but not atheistic. They believe that they don't know or that they can't know, and see that as a different position to atheism (which they equate with your gnostic atheism). Tangentially, the word "Gnosticism" was used for a particular form of religeous belief argued against in some of the New Testament letters in the Bible.

Comment: I would argue that you will hardly find people that claim to know that god doesn't exist. Usually an atheist claims that it's highly unlikely that a deity exist since there is no scientific evidence which suggests this. But it's not possible to "know" it.

Comment: I'd say "insane" may be the best answer, as religions are more or less mutually exclusive.

Comment: Arguably an agnostic could be equally uncertain about all deity myths...

Comment: `If an 'atheist' is someone that does not believe in all deities ` This is not correct. an 'atheist' is someone that does not believe in *ANY* deities.

Comment: Cautious? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: While I'd agree there are many routes to atheism, which just means believing in at least one deity, I wouldn't "usually subcategorise" any part of atheism into gnostic atheism; it's a blip. A self-proclaimed "gnostic atheist" either doesn't understand the definition or is simply a nutbag —frankly— in the same group gnostic theists. There's a fair bit of redundancy but [this post defines 17 sorts of atheism](http://commonsenseatheism.com/?p=6487).

Comment: If atheism is zero faith, then the "polar" opposite of zero is still zero faith.

Comment: As an atheist I also don't believe in the morally ambiguous and evil gods

Comment: @user13107 is right, the question is flawed. Red answers the question "[What is the opposite of atheism?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/182190/37177)" and vickyace answers "[What would you call someone that believed in 'all deities' equally?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/182080/37177)"

Comment: Augy has a point. Equal belief in all religions also implies equal _dis_belief in all religions.

Comment: How can you believe in all gods? That is not possible. There are far too many. What about gods that exist and you don't know about? Can you believe in them also?

Comment: Fwiw, the term "agnostic" was coined by a gentleman who thought his atheist fellows spent too much energy on being anti-religion.

Comment: A 'vacuum' is not the rejection of all matter.

Comment: Many religions hold that its God is the one and only true God.  So they are mutually exclusive.  The only way to believe in all of them equally is if the level of belief is zero.  So you are back to Atheist as someone who believes in all deities equally.

Comment: That is perfect... I was leaning towards Kathenotheist which believes in all gods equally, just one at a time... but I think these would be about the same... So thank you for the interjection.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Pantheism](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pantheism) :

> the worship of all gods of different creeds, cults, or peoples indifferently ; also :  toleration of worship of all gods.

So you could say he is "pantheist."

Comment: I found the same definition in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pantheism); could you please credit the source?

Comment: It is from Merriam Webster's.

Comment: Note that this word is more often used in a different sense, the notion that God is the totality of everything that exists.  (The linked dictionary definition seems to be missing this sense, unless that's what they meant by sense 1; anyhow, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantheism )

Comment: WP also suggests "[omnism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnism)" as more closely corresponding to the word the OP wants, but it's not a word I had previously heard of.

Comment: Pantheism is acceptance of "all gods", not "all religions."  Most major religions have contradictory beliefs entirely apart from their iconography or the names of their gods.

Answer (score 6):

'Theism', in it's broadest sense is the belief that at least one deity exists. From that, I'd say that 'Theist' may be the most obvious opposite to 'Atheist'.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/theism

Comment: "Theist" is to "atheist" what "pagan" and "gentile" are to "christian" and "jew".  It's not so much an opposite as it is an indicator of religious disagreement.

Comment: Lexical semantics typically dictates that there are only some words that have direct, binary opposites. 'Atheist' isn't a word that makes up one of these binary pairs but for the ease of description I was loose with the term 'opposite'. http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atheism

Answer (score 5):

[Syncretism](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/syncretism):

> the combination of different forms of belief or practice

It does not have the technical meaning that the OP was seeking, but in practical terms it may accurately describe a specific person's attitude, whereas "pantheism" could be confusing because the intended meaning is the less common usage.

Comment: Wouldn't syncretism also describe an atheistic jew, or a neo-pagan who incorporates significant portions of Christianity into their beleifs?

Comment: @DougM: Yes, syncretism is broader than the requested definition, particularly since it applies to practices and not just affirmation of the existence of a god...but that does not mean it isn't the best word for it. Part of my point was that nobody believes in all gods, so we should consider words that describe actual behaviors and beliefs. Indeed, I think that "all gods" is itself a nonsensical concept.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure such a thing is possible, and hence there may not be a word for it.

Many religious systems gift their deities with exclusive rights over the universe - Christianity is a good example. Isiah 45:5 states: "I am the LORD, and there is no other, besides me there is no God." It would be impossible to reconcile the existence of this god (and still hold them as a god in the sense that their religion requires) with, for example, the Hindu pantheon of multiple gods, who co-exist together. The two are mutually exclusive, and hence a position that believes in both simultaneously is contradictory.

Given the religious impossibility of the belief, it's quite likely its advocates would not have a formal name. Formal names for these types of beliefs tend to come from a history of academic study into the ideas behind them, through theology and philosophy particularly. Given that these disciplines are more or less rigorous they tend to exclude positions that are obviously untenable, and don’t name them specifically but lump them together as nonsensical.

If there is a name for the belief in all gods simultaneously it will likely be informal – “new age” beliefs, for example, or "omnism" as suggested in a comment above.

Comment: I think the nonsense is even worse than this -- how could a person believe in "all gods". Can he believe in gods that he's never heard of? Does is just mean that he believes in every god that anyone else tells him about?

Comment: @adam.r mainly because of how I can work it into MY churches creedo... http://churchofthepaddedwall.org/blog/2013/08/29/pascalian-reservism-pascals-wager/

Answer (score 0):

[Polytheism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytheism) is the belief in **multiple** gods but not necessarily all.

[Pantheism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantheism)  - Pan (all) theism (god) can be interpreted to mean recognising all gods or it can mean all *is* God. In a modern context it is more suitably the former.

Either way, this would not treat all gods equally, however as some gods will be more or less plausible to different people, such as the [Flying Spaghetti Monster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_spaghetti_monster) which is made up as a joke/protest.

Comment: 'such as the Flying Spaghetti Monster which is made up' - as opposed to...?

Comment: @DaveP I lol'd at your response... ahhhhhhh religion...